# Axios - count object

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to count the amount of axios loaded.

For example:I tried by using this script to get the amount of axios load but failed to get the length of the response. Is there anyway to do this?

```
if(isset($get)){
    foreach(*statement*){
        axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '*api link*',
        data: ''
        }).then(function (response) {
        if(response.status===200){
            if(response.data.data!==''){
                console.log(response);
            }
            else{
                //do nothing 
            }   
        }
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are looking for `response.data` ?

Comment: I want to get the amount of objects. If refer to this image, I want it to be 10.

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code you have to make the image? Those all look like individual responses from different axios calls.

Comment: @Jhecht please have a look to updated answer.

Comment: because i am using for loop to do this. meaning to say that there are few API to pass the data.

Comment: You could look into refactoring your code into [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead of the for loop? Without knowing what you are trying to do, it's difficult to give a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to look into it and edit on my code.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, `axios` is an **HTTP** library. What you're trying to count is the number of objects (responses). The response contains a lot of other properties. You can find your data by accessing `response.data`. And finally, if you want to count them, just attach the `length` to it.

```
response.data.length
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `reponse.data`, the actual data passed back from the API, right? You can count the keys in it for a length. Note that this won't go through nested objects.

`console.log(Object.keys(response.data).length)`

Comment: i get "undefined" on my console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this type console, i think you will get total loaded response data (this will not work if you have nested object).
`console.log(Object.keys(response.data).length)`

Comment: i tried with the one you gave but on my console is "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried this and it's work fine

```
response.data.Data.length
```

Hope this will help someone